# Can I post email correspondence between myself and my apartment community Property Manager online?

Tags: civil-law

I live in a fairly upscale apartment community in a major city in Florida. I've been having major issues concerning building security and another matters that I tried to address with our property manager. Her response was dismissive, rude, argumentative and did not even address most of the issues that I brought up.  I followed up with her again and her reply was even more dismissive and arrogant.  Currently I'm trying to take my problems with our property manager with the management company ( You're very large and on apartment communities around the Southeast).  In case this doesn't go anywhere, I would like to warn another people in a review about living here.  I would like to post the emails in the review, redacted for privacy and removing any personal information to provide receipts and backup my claims.  If I did so, would that be illegal in any way?

Answer (score 1):

> would that be illegal in any way?

No, since you are taking the precaution of redacting for privacy and removing third-parties' personal/identifying information.

In fact, publishing records that support your assertions is likelier to discourage the landlord about filing a defamation lawsuit. That is because you are pre-emptively disclosing evidence that your assertions are truthful, and *truth* is an absolute defense in claims of defamation. An analogous rationale applies to other forms of retaliation that the landlord might be tempted to incur.

Comment: Agree on the conclusion, but unless there were something unusual about their contents, I don't think there would be anything illegal about publishing even if the e-mails were unredacted.

Comment: @bdb484 Maybe, but in any case it is better to err on the safe side. For instance, if another tenant is a victim of stalking/harassment, that tenant will not appreciate the publishing [on the Internet] of information that can facilitate the harasser's purpose of figuring out the tenant's home address.